# Is there something similar in android to the iOS developer program from Apple?

Tags: android, ios, google-play

All,

I am looking at building a proprietary app for all platforms. One of the things I found with apple was they have a developer program which we can use to build, debug, distribute and update apps without putting it out on the store. This seems pretty cool even though it comes at a cost ($299/year).

Is there something similar for android where we can update and distribute apps for android without having to go through the play store? I see my phone has an option to install third party apps but there is also a restriction from my carrier (ATT/USA) that totally make it useless because i cannot install apps from outside the play store.

PS: please suggest the appropriate tags for this question too. I am not sure if the current tags are appropriate

Comment: Typically this is very simple on Android devices (Unlike Apple products whereby you're limited to the number of installs unless you pay for the upgraded enterprise program.) ATT removed this restriction mid 2011 to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Google offers an excellent developer program - and it is free!

http://developer.android.com/index.html

They offer GUI based editors for free - Studio and Eclipse based - Studio is new and simple - but Eclipse is mature and if you already know it a popular choice.

Comment: The play store is also available for Free (or a revenue share if you charge for your apps).  It is a lot simpler and quicker than the Apple  app distribution model.

Comment: Testflight App is also a great tool if you are developing Android and iOS apps and need to work with testers.

Comment: I think you will find that Testflight has been pulled from Android use, Apple bought the company.

Comment: Ah - so sad - we have still got Android apps in ours - but I did notice them asking for us to accept new terms and conditions when I logged in today.  I guess it is just a question of time.  Shame - it provided an elegant solution to mobile testing - and that is why Apple purchased them!

Comment: @All: Thank you for the reply and the comments. I did have a look at the link provided and I was aware of that. I was looking more for a solution to distribute apps to people only within the organisation and not put the app out in the market for people to download. Is that something that android offers? From what I understand, apple provides this with their model but it costs $299 per year

Comment: Google play does support private distribution models - as well as alpha, beta testing.